# Scrolled bar option issue in wxpython script

Tags: wxpython

i created a scrolled bar below the frame we have a panel, but in that panel initially scrolled bar option is not visible after minimize and maximize scrolled bar is appearing.
style = (wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX |
wx.NO_BORDER | wx.CAPTION | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
wx.Frame.**init**(self, None, title="List of Active Processes", style=style, size=(400, 430))

```
    ico = wx.Icon(r'UI/Hitachi_symbol.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
    self.SetIcon(ico)

    self.active_panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1, size=(400, 400),      style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
    self.active_panel.SetupScrolling()
```

My expecting is after executing scrolled bar option is not appearing. after minimize and maximize the frame will able to see the scrolled bar

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be concentrating on the style of the Frame in your question, when the style of the ScrolledPanel, in this case, is key.
Normally the parameters used in `SetupScrolling` define how scrolling will function, combined with what is placed within the panel, size wise.
In this case, where you always require the scroll bars to be visible, you can set the `style` of the `ScrolledPanel` to `wx.ALWAYS_SHOW_SB`.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as SP

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title="Scroll"):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title)

        self.active_panel = SP.ScrolledPanel(self, -1, size=(400, 400), style=wx.ALWAYS_SHOW_SB)
        self.active_panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.active_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#ffffff')
        fixed_text = wx.StaticText(self.active_panel, -1, label="Some fixed text for the panel", pos=(20,50))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.active_panel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = MyFrame()
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]